# Making bar chart from list

Tags: python, list, diagram

Stuck with this problem. I have list `[6,7,7,8,10]`. I need to make diagram like below.

```
 6 *
 7 **
 8 *
 9 
10 *
```

Comment: Are the values sorted? What is your own attempt?

Answer (score 1):

if the list is sorted and you only want the diagram for numbers from the first to last.

```
a = [6, 7, 7, 8, 10]
for i in range(a[0], a[-1] + 1):
    print(i, sum([ k==i for k in a])*'*')
```

for this to work on unsorted list replace `a[0]` by `min(a)` and `a[-1]` by `max(a)`.

if you don't want to print the zero entries, replace the `range` object with `sorted(set(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [6, 7, 7, 8, 10] 

for item in range(min(data), max(data) + 1):
    print item, data.count(item) * '*'
```

Output:

```
6 *
7 **
8 *
9
10 *
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work on a unsorted list aswell:

```
l = [6,7,7,8,10]

for i in range(min(l), max(l) + 1):
  print("%d: %s " % (i, '*' * l.count(i)))
```

**Output:**

```
6: * 
7: ** 
8: * 
9:  
10: *
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FhG3/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with dictionaries for this task ;

```
a=input()
d={}
# this function is used to generate the dictionary for your hitogram
def histogram(a):
    for i in a:
        try:
            d[i]=d.get(i)+1
        except:
            d[i]=1
# to display the histogram
def display(d):
    x=d.keys()
    x.sort()
    for i in x:
        print i,'*'*d[i]
```

Now checking for executing time :

```
import time
t=time.time()
a=[6,7,7,8,10]
d={}
def histogram():
    for i in a:
        try:
            d[i]=d.get(i)+1
        except:
            d[i]=1
histogram()
t1=time.time()
print t1-t

>>> 4.6968460083e-05
```